# How to create unique widget area on page created base on template?

Tags: wordpress

I have a theme PHP page template for pages that are created through WordPress admin interface. Is it possible to add unique widget area to every created page?

I don't want to add widget area with static ID to the PHP template, because when I add widget to that area, it will appear on all pages inheriting the template.

I would like to have unique widget area on every page created by WordPress admin interface.

Comment: I think it would be better to give a reason why you want to do this. Doing this could get out of hand real quick (performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.

1) use a separate template for each group of pages that should use a particular widget area, the group could contain a single page.

2) write code that creates widget areas based on the slug for the page.

These have various advantages and disadvantages.  Using separate templates is easier and allows you to have classes of pages, eg. all "services" or "portfolio" pages.  The slug based system lets you target individual pages.  Be sure to add the slug to the body class so you can target CSS by page.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a unique template-file for each page. "page-1.php", "page-2.php" etc.

Maybe, this plugin can make the trick? http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/